# Will I be able to pass through immigration and customs from foreign country to the U.S with damaged green card after an absence of more than one year?

Tags: usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, colombia

BY THE WAY I have lot of proof of residency in the U.S even my colombian passport was processed in the colombian embassy in New York Lol, and also the stamps of previous admittance.

Edit - Wow thanks to everyone that has been so kind and have replied to my post I really appreciate your concern as well as time and effort, didnt expect this much help hehe, basically I was worried about the not let being out of the country I'm in, Thanks to everyone for the help and I meant it  as I did not get a permit to come back to the u.s since my Green card was already expired before I left the u.s. it's just that I bent it by accident while being here, and I'm sorry about not being able to explain you better in a more detailed way since I was in a rush.

Thank you.

To make the story short, I've been in a country of which I'm a citizen of since Jan 2018, I had to come and take care of family matters, I really had no way of getting a permit to stay longer because it was an emergency, and ended up staying until now. I know I've stayed for too long, but this is not my first time and I´ve been admitted back to the U.S after staying a little longer than I should have.

This time though my green card is a little damaged but still in one piece, just bent at the middle, also it expired not too long ago, but my main concern is if I should be clear of getting through immigration from this country. If I talk to the immigration officer and explain to him the situation, I know when I get to the U.S they will definitely pull out my file and it will be confirmed that I'm valid, I'll deal with whatever I have to like before. I'm just desperate at this point, I really want to go to what I call home.

Comment: I’m not 100% sure I understand your question. Are you asking if you’ll have problems exiting the country you’re currently in because of your expired, damaged green card? Or whether you’ll be allowed to board a flight back to the US (assuming you need to)? Or whether you’ll have a problem when you try to enter the US? Or some/all of the above?

Comment: The quality of the question is really poor, I do understand that you are desperate but you should make your question more clear. People who read it won't understand hence they will not be able to help you.

Comment: I don't know what is your real concern: overstayed, damaged greencard, expired greencard ? Also maybe you want to keep it for you but the country you've been to would be a relevant information.

Comment: Whether departure control officers in your country of citizenship will allow you to leave with a damaged expired green card depends on which country it is.  But  it doesn't much matter; see my answer for details.

Comment: @stbr unless by "overstayed" you mean spending too much time outside the US, overstaying is not possible here since Johnnyboy91 is in his country of citizenship.

Comment: @phoog That's what I understand here: "I really had no way of getting a permit to stay longer because it was an emergency." Did I got it wrong ?

Comment: @stbr "overstay" usually implies staying for too long *in* a place, but the "permit to stay" here is probably a reentry permit, which is a permit to stay *away from* the US for up to 2 years.

Comment: So if you stay longer than what you are allowed you basically overstayed, that's just what the word means .. It does not mean he was outlaw but he did overstay.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help i meant as indid not get a permit to get out of the u.s before i left with my expired green card so I could come back

Answer (score 10):

Departure controls in your country of citizenship are not the problem here.  The green card is not legally sufficient to return to the US after more than 1 year of absence.  Furthermore, an airline is unlikely to allow you to board a flight to the US with an expired green card.  You should apply for a [returning resident visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/returning-resident.html).

> A permanent resident (called lawful permanent resident or LPR) or conditional resident (CR) who has remained outside the United States for longer than one year, or beyond the validity period of a Re-entry Permit, will require a new immigrant visa to enter the United States and resume permanent residence. A provision exists under U.S. visa law for the issuance of a returning resident special immigrant visa to an LPR who remained outside the United States due to circumstances beyond his/her control. This webpage is about Returning Resident Visas. If you are an LPR unable to return to the United States within the travel validity period of the green card (1 year) or the validity of the Re-entry Permit (2 years), you may be eligible and can apply at the nearest U.S. Embassy or Consulate for a Returning Resident (SB-1) immigrant visa.

Comment: Note that airlines *are* allowed by the US government to board passengers to the US with an expired 10-year green card. However, I am not sure if any airlines will do so.

Comment: @user102008 They have to, as TIMATIC doesn't instruct them otherwise. Thus, if denied boarding you'd be eligible for compensation, if applicable in the departure country

Comment: @user102008 can you please explain further into this information if you can thank you

Comment: @Crazydre hello sir, are you positive on this? Im literally ready to buy my ticket like now but I've been afraid they dont let me out of this country, last time one of these colombian immgration officers told me he would not let me out to board with a worn out green card wtf

Comment: @Johnnyboy91 That's not their job, so he was in the wrong. Like I said, 10-year green cards can be expired, and if the check-in staff (where you drop bags) doesn't know that, ask them to check TIMATIC

Comment: @Crazydre thank you for your reply, well I've heard that these immigration officers for admitting people to board to the U.S are required by the U.S government to only board allowed legally documented people on airlines or else there could be penalties, but I'm not really sure, thought that's what all my family has been telling me, just risk it and go home, Im just scared I run into this dude again and he denies me boarding and I ose my money too I did not know all these information your providing me, is there anywhere I could print this from so I could have legal proof to show them?

Comment: @Johnnyboy91 It's the check-in staff's job to check your papers for the US, **not** that of Colombian immigration. In particular, Colombian immigration cannot possibly know all the complex rules of different countries, while check-in staff have a database for that

Comment: @Crazydre I see, it's pretty clear to me know thanks so much for your help, I'm going to just buy the ticket

Comment: @Johnnyboy91 What airline are you flying with? You could email the local handling agent at the Colombian airport and clear this up in advance so as to avoid potential delays

Comment: @Johnnyboy91 Also, you should press the button below the down arrow to accept whichever answer answers your question the best.

Comment: @Crazydre "that's not their job": are you certain? There's nothing that prevents Colombia from requiring departing travelers to be able to prove that they are admissible at their destination.  In particular, there are posts on this site that indicate that India does this for at least some of its citizens.  *If* any country's officers do that, however, it's not because of penalties imposed by the destination country.  That is of course the situation of *airlines,* so the information described in Johnnyboy91's comment seems to be a little confused.

Comment: @phoog I'm in contact with OP regarding this; he's going to discuss the matter with the local ground handler in Medellin. And no, immigration officers in MERCOSUR states don't employ the practice you mention

Answer (score 3):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Additional Information: An **expired** Permanent Resident/Resident Alien Card (Form I-551) is accepted with:

- **a 10-years validity at time of issuance**; or
- a Transportation Letter issued by the USA; or
- a civilian or military travel order issued by the USA or
  if the passenger is included as dependent spouse or child on
  the civilian or military travel order.

That said, you've been out of the US for too long and so, worst case, could be brought before an immigration judge to establish whether you've reliquinshed permanent residency. **However**, if you have lots of evidence of your ties to the US, and also of the situation that forced you to stay abroad for so long, you should be OK.

Comment: Do I have to fill this form out from the u.s embassy here? or can i just go ahead and catch a flight next week with that bent worn out expired green card, it expired a year ago or so

Comment: @Johnnyboy91 What form? No form is required. If your green card is whole, the information legible and your face visible, you're good to go

Comment: hey man again thank you for all the help sorry to bother you but you are the light i was looking for lol do you mind if i post the documents and you can judge? Ill edit them obviously

Comment: I deleted some comments, if you still need them ping me and I will undelete temporarily.